# problem with a string and parse XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xcode, string

I have a logical condition that does not work. it would compare two characters, one taken from the xml and the other I insert myself.

to let you know I am attaching below the code

```
NSString *telefono = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrayColonnine objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"telefono"]];
NSString *trimmedTelefono = [telefono stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
        senzaTelefono = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[trimmedTelefono stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



if (telefono == @"NO")
if (trimmedTelefono == @"NO")
if (senzaTelefono == @"NO")
```

for each of the three strings if I do a log it print NO. but in none of the three cases the if works. how can I fix to make it work?

**SOLUTION**

the process is just this:

```
NSString *telefono = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[arrayColonnine objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"telefono"]];
NSString *trimmedTelefono = [telefono stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([trimmedTelefono isEqualToString:@"NO"]) {
 //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use isEqualToString:

```
    if ([telefono isEqualToString:@"NO"])
```

`if (telefono == @"NO")` compares the objects being the same, not the contents being the same.

Comment: Thanks CocoaFu, I solved the problem by putting isEqualToString but using also whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `==` to compare NSString objects.